# fitsSystemWindows и меню Text Edit Actions

Tags: android, activity, android-themes

В приложении есть активити с такой темой

```
<style name="EnterTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/main_white_100</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogCustom</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/main_white_100</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/main_purple</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_stripes</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MainButton</item>
</style>
```

Обнаружилось, что меню Text Edit Actions показывается криво на многих телефонах. На моем у текста пропадал paddingStart, на MIUI вообще все разъезжалось к ... Сильно в общем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Закомментировал все опции - проблема исчезла, начал возращать по одной - после раскомментирования

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

стало проявляться опять.

Можно конечно убрать эту опцию, но не хотелось бы, так как она решает определенную проблему. Не сталкивались ли вы с подобным? Может быть как то можно решить проблему не убирая fitsSystemWindows?

Comment: Так может проставлять этот атрибут именно тем виджетам, для которых он _решает определенную проблему_  , а не всем разом?

Comment: Оно решает проблему для одного из трех фрагментов, хостящегося в активити, там отдельными виджетами не пахнет. Пробовал для decorView проставлять на старте и убирать на дестрое фрагмента - не было эффекта. В итоге убрал этот аттрибут и подошел к решению той проблемы с другой стороны, правда пока не нашёл окончательного решения

Comment: Все контейнеры тоже наследники `View` - соответственно атрибут можно задать группе, например, корневому контейнеру фрагмента. А поскольку всё содержимое контейнера позиционируется относительно него же, то в теории должно получиться, что весь фрагмент будет учитывать этот атрибут.

Answer (score 2):

Поведение в вашем случае вполне предсказуемое, согласно статьи
https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec

> Any other padding you’ve set is overwritten — you’ll note that `paddingLeft/paddingTop/etc` is ineffective if you are using `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` on the same View

Там же описано как кастомизировать поведение `android:fitsSystemWindows` для любого `View`.